# Convert .toString() to Timestamp object

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Anyone know how to convert string "Timestamp(second=16698..., nanoseconds=187...)" from Google Firestore to a Dart Timestamp object?

I couldn't find anything with this particular example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this function, adjust it to suit your case

```
    customTimeStamp(String strSeconds) {
    final seconds = strSeconds.substring(
        strSeconds.indexOf('=') + 1, strSeconds.indexOf(','));
    final nanoSeconds = strSeconds.substring(
        strSeconds.lastIndexOf('=') + 1, strSeconds.indexOf(')'));
    return Timestamp(
        int.tryParse(seconds) ?? 0, int.tryParse(nanoSeconds) ?? 0);
  }
```